# Opencart - file option and price calculation

Tags: php, opencart, shopping-cart

i'm trying to make e-shop for business cards, brochures and etc printing. So main option is file upload option.
The problem is that opencart not recalculating prices if user uploaded different files. Lets say customer want to order 100 business cards with one picture (price is 0.2$ each when amount is 100 ) and 1000 business cards with another picture (0.1$ each when amount is 1000), in total it should be 120$, but opencart showing 110$ :

-business card (file1.pdf) x100  0.1$

-business card (file2.pdf) x1000  0.1$

Total 110$

i want that prices would be recalculated if uploaded files are not same :

-business card (file1.pdf) x100  0.2$

-business card (file2.pdf) x1000  0.1$

Total 120$

How can i do this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to customize OpenCart. You can use vqmod to insert code without changing the core code.

Comment: @Revent i'm working with vqmod on this for couple days , but no success, i couldn't find where i should make changes to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution could be very simple:

1. make the default business card price like $0.35 for less then 100 pcs ordered
2. set a discount on that business card product in this way:

   1. more than 100 pcs ordered - price is $0.2 for a piece
   2. more than 1000 pcs ordered - price is $0.1/pcs
3. now when client orders 100 pcs (one product, one file) and another 1000 pcs (same product, different file - should be different *option*), the price(s) should be calculated accordingly.

e.g.

```
100x    BusinessCard (file1.pdf) $0.2 = $20
1000x   BusinessCard (file2.pdf) $0.1 = $100
```

Comment: the problem is that this doesn't work, when option have no price.